# how to really understand kfold cross validation in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use kfold in sklearn and really trying to understand what its doing. I am reading Python machine learninb 3rd edition by Sebastian Raschka.

In chapter 6 https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book-3rd-edition/blob/master/ch06/ch06.ipynb

He has a code for StratifiedKFold

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10).split(X_train, y_train)
scores = []
for k, (train, test) in enumerate(kfold):
    pipe_lr.fit(X_train[train], y_train[train])
    score = pipe_lr.score(X_train[test], y_train[test])
    scores.append(score)
    print('Fold: %2d, Class dist.: %s, Acc: %.3f' % (k+1,
          np.bincount(y_train[train]), score))

print('\nCV accuracy: %.3f +/- %.3f' % (np.mean(scores), np.std(scores)))
```

1. I am not sure when he is instantiating kfold uses only train set? why not the whole set?

So looking at kfold cross validation documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html this time they split the whole set but only X dataset.

2. Why this time split whole dataset but only X?

So I am trying to use 10-fold cross validation, below is my code

```
gbr_onehot = GradientBoostingRegressor(
n_estimators  = 1000,
learning_rate = 0.1,
random_state  = 0
)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0).split(X)

train_score = []
test_score  = []

for k, (train, test) in enumerate(kfold):
    gbr_onehot.fit(X[train], y[train])

    train_pred = gbr_onehot.predict(X[train])
    train_score.append(metrics.mean_squared_error(train_pred, y[train]))

    test_pred  = gbr.onehot.predict(X[test])
    test_score.append(metrics.mean_squared_error(test_pred, y[test]))
```

which gives me`KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([    0,     1,     2,     3,     4,     5,     6,     7,     9,\n               10,\n            ...\n            18313, 18314, 18315, 18316, 18317, 18318, 18319, 18320, 18321,\n            18322],\n           dtype='int64', length=16490)] are in the [columns]`

I've been using cross_val_score however I want to get train set's mse.

I've read many SO questions, and others however still confused.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure when he is instantiating kfold uses only train set? why
>   not the whole set?

The proper way is to leave a sample to test if your model generalize well. However, KFold is to average the performance of the model while training, so the error will be averaged by holding one split at time. So every split will be held to verify and average the performance ***in-the-sample***. Then the split you hold (say 0.25 of the overall dataset and which not included in the KFold), will be used to test the ***out-of-sample*** (for generalization purposes).

> Why this time split whole dataset but only X?

Because they are giving an example about the ***use*** of the function, for the sake of the example not anything else. If they hole one split for testing the out-of-sample, they may confuse the reading about the inner-functionality of KFold.

> The Error

It seems X != Y as an initial guess. However, use your IDE to point to the exact location of the problem.